# No ads are loading on amp-mode-touch

Tags: php, amp-html

Like the title says. I’ve successfully placed adsense ads on my AMP posts. While testing it out on my desktop via firebug, adverts are coming up as intended. However, I cannot get any ads to come up on my mobile? The pages body class changes to amp-mode-touch and the adverts div containers disappear completely.

Here is an example URL - http://www.gamersgreed.com/kingdom-come-deliverance-fps-boost-optimization/amp

And here is the code i'm using to produce the ads -

```
//Insert ads after third and seventh paragraph of any single post content.

add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );

function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {

    $ad_code = '<div style="text-align: center;"><amp-ad width=300         height=250
type="adsense"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-7568065840567088"
data-ad-slot="1234194857">
<div placeholder></div>
<div fallback></div>
</amp-ad>
</div>
';

$ad_code2 = $ad_code;

if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
   $content = prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
   $content = prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code2, 7, $content );

return $content;
}
return $content;
}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen

function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content     ) {
$closing_p = '</p>';
$paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

    if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
        $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
    }

    if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
        $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
    }
}

return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Comment: Still having issues with this.